# Implementing AES Encryption/Decryption around existing PHP System on Android

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, aes

I'm expanding an iOS project over to Android. My existing application communicates with a server via PHP using an AES encryption system.

Here are the functions that I am using on the PHP side:

**Encrypt**

```
function cryptAESEncrypt($string,$key) {
    $key = md5($key);
    $iv = "1234567890123436"; //IV isn't needed if MCRYPT_MODE is ECB (What we are using)
    $data = $data = base64_encode($string);
    $algorythm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
    $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key,$data,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,$iv);

    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

**Decrypt**

```
function cryptAESDecrypt($string,$key) {
    $key = md5($key);
    $iv = "1234567890123436"; //IV isn't needed if MCRYPT_MODE is ECB (What we are using)
    $data = base64_decode($string);
    $algorythm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
    $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key,$data,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,$iv);

    return base64_decode($decrypted);
}
```

The general flow of the process is:

- md5 hash the `$key` (brings it down to 16 characters regardless)
- Base64 Encode the `$string`
- Encrypt the Base64'ed using 128Bit AES/RIJNDAEL in ECB mode (no IV)
- Base64 the encrypted data and returns it as a string.

The decryption works the same but in reverse.

Now I'm just playing with samples but don't seem to be having much luck. I've encrypted the string `"test"` in PHP using that function (`"test"` was the key too - MD5'ed to `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`) and I am given the output of `"ijzLe/2WgbaP+n3YScQSgQ=="`.

Now what I tried in Java didn't work as I get an incorrect key length error but I had more luck with a previous snippet earlier. Here's what I had anyway:

```
String key = "test";
String in = "ijzLe/2WgbaP+n3YScQSgQ==";

SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(md5(key).getBytes(), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

byte[] encryptedByteArray = Base64.decode(in.getBytes(),0);
byte[] decryptedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(encryptedByteArray);
String decryptedData = new String(Base64.decode(decryptedByteArray, 0));

Log.v("NOTE","Data: "+decryptedData);
```

As I said though, that doesn't work. Now my question is, is there anybody that can help me make my Java code work with the supplied PHP code as I can't change that (had other code working using different PHP snippets).

Comment: Why use encryption at all, if you don't use secure encryption?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace you get when running the Java example. Also, please show your `md5` method.

Comment: Ahh! Thanks! It was the MD5 function missing out zeros giving an incorrect key!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Duncan in the comments I found out the issue was with my MD5 hash function..

Found a working version for reference:

```
public String md5(String s) {
    if (s != null)
    {
        try { // Create MD5 Hash
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest .getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(s.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            // Create Hex String
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                while (h.length() < 2)
                    h = "0" + h;
                hexString.append(h);
            }
            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}
```